# undefined reference to `function_name'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, reference, linker, undefined

I moved from Windows to Ubuntu and I wanted to try some C++ programming on Ubuntu. So here is very simple code and very stupid error which I can't resolve:

horse.h

```
#ifndef _horse_
#define _horse_

class Horse{

int speed;

public:

void saySomething();

};

#endif
```

horse.cpp

```
#include "horse.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Horse::saySomething(){
    cout << "iiiihaaaaaaa brrrrr."<<endl;
}
```

and Main.cpp

```
#include "horse.h"

int main(){

    Horse h;

    h.saySomething();

}
```

After I compile (compilation is successful) and run this I get this error message:

```
/tmp/ccxuDyrd.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `Horse::saySomething()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me somehow.

Comment: How did you compile this?

Comment: This is a linker error. Does `gcc Main.cpp horse.cpp` work?

Comment: Yes. Compilation is successful. I get .o files but executable file cannot be made.

Comment: You said you moved from windows to a Linux environment? If you invoked something like `gcc Main.ccp horse.cpp`, your "executable" is produced as "a.out". You call it like ./a.out

Comment: @Ben If I invoke g++ Main.cpp horse.cpp I get a.out and when I start that a.out, it works. I just wanted to make the object files first and then link them properly. But if anyone don't know how to do that, I will just always do like you said , just instead of gcc i will use g++ :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`g++ -c main.cpp horse.cpp` (to compile)

`g++ -o a.out main.o horse.o` (to link)

Comment: After the first command, g++ -c main.cpp horse.cpp, compiler makes a.out and I don't even need to link the files. I can just invoke ./a.out and the program will work. Thanks :)
Just erase the second command.

Comment: This works and this solved my problem, but I just don't understand how can this work without object files and linking...

Comment: Are you sure?! `g++ -c` is supposed to only compile to object files, not link them. Second command should link the produced object files. I don't have ubuntu, but at least this is the behaviour on OS X.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to type -c, I typed g++ Main.cpp horse.cpp command and that have made a.out. After that I can run a.out and program works, but in the folder there are no object files which is confusing for me

Comment: You should really take some time to read about compilers and linkers - it's not a very tough read. "-c" tells gcc/g++ to compile but not invoke the linker, the result are the object files.

Comment: Now I've typed exactly what you said and that worked perfectly!!! Thank you very much. (It also works if you just type
 g++ Main.cpp horse.cpp )

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only compiled your code but did not link the resulting object files. You probably invoked the compiler like this:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

You should instead compile every *.cpp file separately and then link each resulting *.o file. And you should do this with a Makefile.

Actually, the basic idea is the same on Windows with MSVC. The compiler produces object files, the linker links them together.

Comment: I have made the object files (Main.o and horse.o), I just don't know how to link them without getting this error.

Comment: @user3688779: are you asking how to use the linker, or have you actually tried it and it didn't work?

Comment: I have tried it, and linker says /tmp/ccxuDyrd.o: In function `main':
Main.cpp:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to `Horse::saySomething()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: How do you invoke the linker? What do you type?

Comment: g++ -Wall -o "Main" "Main.cpp" (in directory: /home/etf/Desktop/gcctest/cpptest)

Comment: horse.o will have to be included in your linking statement (as per vsoftco's answer)